# rsync script works, but not when scheduled via cron

Tags: cron, rsync, nfs

I'm trying to execute a shell script to run an 'rsync' process that sync's a local directory on a server to an NFS mount, mounted on the same server.  I am running a script as "root", that 'sudo's into the user that has permission to write to the NFS mount, and runs another shell script that executes 'rsync'.

When I run this script manually as "root", the script runs successfully.  However, when I schedule the script to run via 'cron', the 'rsync' process begins, but does not complete, stopping at the stage of building the file list.

This is the script, "exec_NFS_rsync.sh" that I run as "root":

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u nfsuser /path/to/scripts/nfs_rsync/scripts/NFS_rsync.sh
```

This is the contents of "NFS_rsync.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

##
## VARIABLES
##

# rsync binary
rsync="/usr/bin/rsync"

# Source
sourcedir="/path/to/source/files/"

# Destination
destdir="/path/to/destination/nfs/mount/"

# Exclude
exclude="--exclude=*.tmp --exclude=tmp/ --exclude=*.lck"

# Log file
log_file="/path/to/log/folder/NFS_rsync.log"

##
## SCRIPT
##

# Check if the log file exists
if [ ! -e $log_file ]; then
        touch $log_file
fi

if [ ! -d $destdir ]; then
        echo "Log destination directory doesn't seem to exist. Please investigate"
        exit 2
fi


# Start entry in the log
echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Local Storage to NFS Sync started." >> $log_file

# Start sync NFS to Local
`$rsync -av --stats --delete $exclude $sourcedir $destdir >> $log_file`

echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Local Storage to NFS Sync completed." >> $log_file


# End entry in the log
echo "" >> $log_file
exit
```

This is the output I receive when running from 'cron':

```
2012-04-05 16:20:01 - Local Storage to NFS Sync started.
building file list ... 2012-04-05 16:20:01 - Local Storage to NFS Sync completed.
```

Note that the "building file list" never is marked as "done".

No file transfer takes place.

This is the 'crontab' entry:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/scripts/nfs_rsync/scripts/exec_NFS_rsync.sh
```

If I run it manually, I get the full verbose output and the transfers complete successfully, followed by stats presented (I won't include it because it's long).

I don't believe it to be a permissions issue, because I can execute the "exec_NFS_rsync.sh" script as "root" from the shell, and can also execute the "NFS_rsync.sh" script directly as the "nfsuser".

This is the 'fstab' entry for the NFS mount:

```
nfsfiler:/path/to/nfs/mount /path/to/destination/nfs/mount/      nfs     hard,intr,nfsvers=3,rw,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 0 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I had a problem running a script in a non-linux filesystem using the syntax `$ ./the_script.sh`. The problem was I could not mark the script as executable in a FAT filesystem. Had to run it like `$ bash the_script.sh`

Comment: Are those backticks around the `rsync` command line a mistake of entry to SO or are those backticks in your actual script, too?

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but are you running a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) system such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)? Any of these could cause the script to execute in a different protection domain due to running out of `cron(8)`. Check `dmesg(1)` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for log messages that look related.

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  This is occurring in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP3 (so not non-Linux), and the file system of the script is "ext3", on local disk.  Yes, they are backticks around the `rsync` command, so that the command is executed.  And no, not mandatory access control system.  It is a relatively vanilla install of the OS.  I don't have a `/var/log/audit/` directory.

Comment: I moved the cron entry to the "nfsuser" crontab, and this now works.  Any thoughts on why I would be able to run it through `cron` this way, but not from the "root" crontab using the `sudo` command?

Comment: I think you should not use sudo in script file because you must have a tty to run sudo.You can use "su" instead of "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying

```
*/10 * * * * su - l nfsuser -c /path/to/scripts/nfs_rsync/scripts/NFS_rsync.sh
```

in your root crontab ?